# BlackBerry. How do you know that the application is launched for the first time after installation?

Tags: blackberry

How do you know that the application is launched for the first time after installation?

And how to do what the code for the application uninstall?

Answer (score 2):

You have to store a value in the PersistentStore. When getting the value for the first time from it you will obtain a null value, meaning that the application is launched for the first time. So you do your work and then save a value into the persistentObject to avoid getting null again. And that's it

Comment: Here's a link to a tutorial on that: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Storing-Persistent-Data/ta-p/442785

Comment: So try reading the persistent object, if null means that it is the first time, so you will have to save your value in it.